# Why is a non-optional value printed as optional?

Tags: swift, printing, option-type

I've read [Non-optional shown as optional on print](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39790567/non-optional-shown-as-optional-on-print) but that doesn't help my question.

I'm returning a Integer, but once it's printing it's being printed as optional. Why?

I'm trying to solve a code challenge. The goal is to:

> Write an extension for collections of integers that returns the number
>   of times a specific digit appears in any of its numbers.

Here is my implementation:

```
extension Collection where Iterator.Element == Int {
    func challenge37(count character : Character) -> Int?{

        guard nil != Int(String(character)) else{
            print("character wasn't an integer")
            return nil
        }

        var counts : [Int] = []
        for item in self{
            var counter = 0
            let stringInt = String(describing: item)

            for currentCharacter in stringInt.characters{
                if character == currentCharacter{
                    counter += 1
                }
            }
            counts.append(counter)
        }
        guard let min = counts.min() else{
            print("no min")
            return nil
        }

        return min
    }
}
```

As you can see here I'm printing it:

```
print([5,15,512,522].challenge37(count: "5")) // Optional(1)
```

Comment: Although the linked question seems very much related, the confusion of the OP is due to not paying attention to *optional* returning type

Comment: The linked question is about the string interpolation of implicitly unwrapped optionals, so I don't think that is very much related. – In your case you have a function returning `Int?` and that is printed as an optional, so I wonder why that is unclear at all (or deserves a self-answered question).

Comment: @MartinR The line `return min` is unwrapped and a newbie might think it should return non-optional

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the function your returning an `Int`. However the actual signature of your method is `Int?` meaning it is in fact an optional and you got it wrong!

Basically your method signature is correct. But when you call the function you're getting an optional as the response and must unwrap it.

```
print([5,15,512,522].challenge37(count: "5")!) // 1
```

Additionally had you paid close attention you would have noticed that Xcode must gave you a warning (and solutions to solve it)

> Expression implicitly coerced from `Int?` to Any

[image]

Xcode gave you the warning because it found out that you're attempting to print an optional and knows that's usually unwanted. Obviously its solution is to unwrap it either through **force unwrap** or **defaulting**.